# VBA Error Compile: Expected: Expression

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on some homework and I can't figure out why my code won't work. The assignment is to request a name then respond in red text in B10.

Here is my code:

[image]

Any help would be great- Thanks!

Comment: pasting your code it here as text and not a picture will be much easier

Comment: Also, what line causes the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Sheets("MyNewSheet").Activate
    With Range("B10")
        .Font.ColorIndex = 3
        strName = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter your name.", Type:=2)
        .Value = strName
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from the line `With RAnge("b10").Font.ColocarIndex = 3`, `With` supose to be used only to objects (not expressions)

```
sName = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter your name.", Type:=2)    
With Sheets("MyNewSheet").Range("B10")
    .Font.ColorIndex = 3
    .Value = sName 
End With
```